# Streamplot python module "ImportError: No module named streamplot"

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to run this code BUT the problem is that `"ImportError: No module named streamplot"`

please help to fix this error

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from streamplot import streamplot

x = np.linspace(-3,3,100)
y = np.linspace(-3,3,100)
u = -1-x**2+y[:,np.newaxis]
v = 1+x-y[:,np.newaxis]**2

speed = np.sqrt(u*u + v*v)    
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(121)
streamplot(x, y, u, v, density=1, INTEGRATOR='RK4', color='b')
plt.subplot(122)

plt.streamplot(x, y, u, v, density=(1,1), 
               INTEGRATOR='RK4', color=u, 
               linewidth=5*speed/speed.max())

plt.show()
```

Comment: Try `matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot`

Comment: I changed each of  "streamplot" to "matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot" and now it says "name 'matplotlib' is not defined"

Comment: Never Mind the last comment. it actually worked; However, there is another error "streamplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'INTEGRATOR'" do you know how to solve this error

Comment: According to its docstring, `streamplot` doesn't have an `INTEGRATOR` argument.  Try removing that argument from your call to `streamplot`.

Comment: An early development version of `streamplot` had an `integrator` argument, but it was removed: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/d60c9fc3386f9670ccc42b844169be807fbaa302